# Making sure VPN is on and connected before going to certain website?

Tags: vpn

Sometimes you access certain sites using VPN. Is there any way to make sure you never visit the site while VPN is off or disconnected?

I am on an windows machine.

Comment: You can create a script that checks if tun0 is connected every second, if not,  activate the panic mode on your firewall.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this.

One way to make sure you never visit the site without the VPN is to make sure you never visit any site without the VPN.

The most basic ways to do that are to remove the default routes (0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0) through the physical network interface and replace them with routes to only the local network and VPN server, or use firewall rules to the same effect. This is operating system specific, but here is an example using iptables:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT --out-interface eth0 -d ${VPN_SERVER_IP} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --out-interface eth0 -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT --out-interface eth0 -j REJECT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT --out-interface eth0 -j REJECT
```

A stronger version of this if your device is always connected to the same network is to do the same thing from a router you put in front of your device, in which case the rules go in FORWARD as well as OUTPUT:

```
iptables -A FORWARD --out-interface eth0 -d ${VPN_SERVER_IP} -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD --out-interface eth0 -j REJECT
ip6tables -A FORWARD --out-interface eth0 -j REJECT
```

Then traffic that goes out eth0 (the internet interface) can only go to the VPN server while traffic through the VPN interface can go anywhere.

But suppose you want other sites to work without the VPN, just not this one. Now you need a way to distinguish it. If you know its IP address you can do something like this:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT --out-interface eth0 -d ${SITE_IP} -j REJECT
iptables -A FORWARD --out-interface eth0 -d ${SITE_IP} -j REJECT
```

However, the site may have multiple IP addresses, may share them with other sites, and they may change at any time. Not great.

Another option could be to configure the DNS server you use when not connected to the VPN to one that refuses to resolve that site, but then you run the risk that your browser or some other code between it and your DNS server has cached the result from when you were on the VPN and uses it after you disconnect.

Moreover, if you use the same browser both on and off the VPN the site may be able to associate the two using third party cookies and similar things.

What you need is something to isolate the browser being used for that site, such as by running it on a virtual machine or separate physical machine which can only connect through the VPN as above.

Finally, note that what you are asking for is a common use case for Tor. Accessing the site only through the Tor browser may accomplish what you are looking for here.

Comment: I see you've added that you're on Windows. Note that it doesn't really change much -- if you put a router in front of your device it would typically run Linux or BSD even if the client is Windows, you can (and should) use a Linux virtual machine to visit that site even if the host is Windows, and the Tor browser also runs on Windows.